# Sum of a part of binomial expansion.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

The calculation of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ can be simply done with $(p+1-p)^n$. But is there any closed form formula for $\sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$? If that is not solvable, is there a closed form formula when $i=\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: The case of general $i $ likely has no closed formula even when $p=1/2$ (in which case it becomes the famous question about partial sums of rows of Pascal's triangle).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [regularised incomplete beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).